# Performing query with specific criteria

Tags: android, database

I want to do a query . I am not sure is it available in android sql db. I want to make a query according to starting and ending character and also the length of the string. 
Suppose,in my db i have hello,how,hurray,honey.I want to take honey from the db and so I want to make a query such as it will find the string starting with "h" and end with "y" and the length of the word is 5.
To do this what my query string will be?

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
select * from `table` where LENGTH(`field`) = 5 and `field` LIKE `h%y`
```

Comment: will you please do me a favor? please write the exact query that i am gonna use in my project . table name=MyTable  , field name =MyField . Am i gonna use sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery() or sqLiteDatabase.Query ?

Comment: select * from `MyTable` where LENGTH(`MyField`) = 5 and `MyField` LIKE "h%y"